# Cycloid variation using theta and radians

Tags: cycloid

I was using matlab to plot these equations
x=a*(theta+sin(theta));
y=a*(1+cos(theta))
which happen to be equation of Cycloid
When I plotted it taking theta in radians
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKOT2.jpg)
I got this plot
While on the other hand using theta in degrees
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Pzx.jpg)

Can anyone explain me why is there such variation and which one is the real cycloid?
Thank you.

Comment: It's the radians' one. The second is a different curve, essentially the cycloid curve with an added $x$ term, i.e. $(x_c,y_c)+a(56.3 \theta,0)$.

Comment: But I have seen a book where a cam- follower profile called cycloid but is the second graph?